# Reordering the columns of a grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik

I am using `Telerik` `grid` controls but I think it should be pretty similar to normal girds: We have a special toggle mode in our forms that if it is set to true, I don't want to be able to reorder the columns of the grid and otherwise want to allow reordering the columns.
I found the event `ColumnReordering` and the property `CanUserReorderColumns`
and used them as following:
**The problem is tha**t it works but **not for the very first time** of reordering the columns, for first time of reordering the columns it still allows it to be reordered but after that it works for other columns.

```
void MyGridView_ColumnReordering(object sender, ColumnReorderingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ThatToggleMode!= null)
    {
        if (this.InThatToggleMode)
        {
            this.CanUserReorderColumns = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.CanUserReorderColumns = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your initial value of `CanUserReorderColumns`?  What happens if you set it to false initially?

Comment: @paqogomez If I set it to False in ctor, then ColumnReordering event is never getting called at all so always remains false.

Answer (score 0):

I just put it in some other method that is getting called before `ColumnReordering` event. By that time it was too late to set the property.